# How to call a class that is created by other function?

Tags: c#, class

I am learning C# as Godot Engine require it. How should I call an object (class) that is created by other function?

Here is my code structure:

```
public class ExampleClass //A random class()
{                         //I heard that I need to set a field for 
   float data;            //other function, How should i do it?
   
   public void SetData(float setData){ //Method in the class
   data = setData;
   }
   ...   // other syntax in class
} 


public void main (){
  float dataStorage;
  ExampleClass Class = new ExampleClass (); //Create new object
  Class.setData(1.0f);
  dataStorage = returnData(); // Call function that return the class 
                              // which is called by main
}

public float returnData (){
  float getData;
  //How should I the call object that is created by main??
  return getData; 
}
```

In short, I would like to know what should I do in order to call the class that is created by other function, thank you!!

Comment: Do you want to use the object created in the ```main``` method in ```returnData``` method?

Comment: @JohnDoe - I believe so, there for I would suggest to simply create a parameter for your method `public float returnData (ExampleClass exampleClass)` and pass it to the method `dataStorage = returnData(Class);` - btw, you should rethink your choice of naming your variable `Class`

Comment: You know you could declare a `public` member? eg. https://dotnetfiddle.net/arLW7E

Answer (score 0):

You may need below code.

```
using System;

namespace ExplicitInterface
{
    public class ExampleClass //A random class()
    {
        //You can define property to get or set the value
        public float SetData { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {

        ExampleClass objClass = new ExampleClass(); //Instantiate class level variable to be used anywhere in the class
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float dataStorage;
            ExampleClass Class = new ExampleClass(); //Create new object
            Class.SetData = 1.0f;
            dataStorage = returnData();
        }

        public float returnData()
        {
            float getData = objClass.SetData;
            return getData;
        }
    }

}
```